# CakePHP: Egregious amount of calls to SELECT count(*)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

CakePHP makes this exact query three times:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `mydb`.`players` AS `Player` WHERE `Player`.`id` = 8
```

When I run:

```
$this->Player->id = $player_id;
$this->Player->save($save_array);
```

It seems CakePHP does this to check if a `Model->save()` should be a create or update entry. I've looked into the issue and have tried to implement the following:

[Force CakePHP to do an update by providing the ID key in the saveFields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html). I thought it would not need to do a `COUNT(*)` if it knew to update every time. That's my real goal, here: something like updateAll that works as `save()` does. Supposing updateAll doesn't make this `COUNT(*)` as well.

[Custom paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723269/unwanted-count-query-in-cakephp), I either did it wrong or it wasn't the problem.

[Changing the model.php(!)](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5270721adee6aa4b2d07a61f589f729092ab9632/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php) was dangerous and ultimately unsuccessful.

I just want to have another function like `save()` that simply updates, so that I can be rid of these `COUNT(*)` queries, but I'm not sure CakePHP supports such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls come from the `Model::exists()` function in the model. You can override that function in your `AppModel`, or any model where you need to prevent this and locally cache the result of the function.

For example, if it gets the `id = 8` in that function you can have an array remembering that this id already exists.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've replaced the "return (bool)" find with a simple "return true" because it seems if I simply the ID, it should already know the record exists. So far I don't see any problems creating or updating any records. Do you know why Cake wants to do a count() here? It seems entirely wasteful if I don't explicitly want to use pagination.

Comment: It does it decide whether to do an insert or an update. There are times when you want to insert a record in the database given a specifc id.

Comment: For all who want a quick solution to this issue, this is my code: http://www.beetxt.com/8fT/